# Verification before delete from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, t-sql

I have a sample website where you enter your e-mail address and it inserts it into an MS SQL database. On the next page a GridView shows the list from the database. Now I need to add a function that deletes an address, but it has to verify if the address is currently

```
public partial class Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = GetLastWriteTime(Request.PhysicalPath).ToString();
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string data = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + "," + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + ": ";

        SqlDataSource1.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO ListaAdresow (Email) Values('" + TextBox1.Text + "')";

        try
        {
            SqlDataSource1.Insert();
            Label2.Text += data + "added into database: " + TextBox1.Text + "<br/>";
            TextBox1.Text = "";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label2.Text += data + ex.Message;
        }
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string data = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + "," + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + ": ";
        SqlDataSource1.DeleteCommand = "DELETE FROM ListaAdresow WHERE Email='" + TextBox1.Text + "'";

        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT  FROM [ListaAdresow] WHERE Email=" + TextBox1.Text;

        try
        {
                SqlDataSource1.Delete();

                Label2.Text += data + "removed from database: " + TextBox1.Text + "<br/>";
                TextBox1.Text = "";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label2.Text += data + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Step 1. Read up on [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Its ok if you delete without checking the database. It wont throw an error if it does not exist, and if it it exists it will be deleted. And as flem suggested research EF, and connect to SQL SERVER using that, using strings like this for data manipulation can be dangerous.

Comment: Step 2. Once you understand why, change your queries to stored procedures, or EF.

Comment: Also your delete command will delete every entry with the same email, which is fine if that is what you intended. However if there can be multiple entries with the same email then I'd suggest using a unique ID instead, and doing inserts/updates/deletes using that.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you create stored procedures for all your querying but for the sake of example, from your gridview you could something as below:

```
if (myGrid.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
{
     int selectedIndex = myGrid.SelectedRows[0].Index;

     // gets the RowID from the first column in the grid
     int rowID = int.Parse(BooksGrid[0, selectedIndex].Value.ToString());

     string sql = "IF EXISTS(SELECT COLUMN FROM Table1 WHERE ID = @rowID)
                    BEGIN 
                      DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID = @rowID"
                    END;

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can verify after execute delete, the method Delete of data source return total of rows affecteds on database. [See documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.delete.aspx).

Comment: So it could be like this? try
        {

                int value = SqlDataSource1.Delete();
   if(value > 0)
                {
                  Label2.Text += data + "removed from database: " +
                     TextBox1.Text + "<br/>";
                  TextBox1.Text = "";
   }
   else
   {
    Label2.Text += data + "mail does not exist in database
   }

             }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
                Label2.Text += data + ex.Message;
           }

Comment: Yes, the return of code show how many rows was affected in database. This is the method more eficient.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you can use something like this (untested):

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    // Create the SelectCommand using paramaterized queries
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * 
                                            FROM ListaAdresow 
                                            WHERE Email = @Email", connection);
    command.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40, TextBox1.Text);

    da.SelectCommand = command;
    da.Fill(dt);

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        //Row Exists
    }
    else
    {
        //Row Does Not Exist
    }
```

However, I reiterate what others have said, the `DeleteCommand` can be run by itself and it will return the number of affected records.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the value in session and the check the session value with delete one before deleting

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a stored procedure and pass value with parameters. In that you can easily check whether data exists in database or not. And also it helps you to prevent somewhat sql injection. :)